# java run out of memory issue

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I have a jar file running on an amazon-ec2-m1.large instance with linux 64bit operating system.
I run out of memory after different hours, usually between 2-4, although in my last log write (before the error file created ) I see the following:

```
Memory - 
     totalHeapSize: 264 MB, 
     maxHeapSize: 1656 MB, 
     freeHeapSize: 220 MB
```

When I look from the jar start until in run out of memory - all values are the same and the freeHeapSize is between 200-230 MB (i check every 30 seconds and do System.gc() )

in the hs_err_pid2250.log wrriten:

```
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
    # Possible reasons:
    #   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
    #   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
    # Possible solutions:
    #   Reduce memory load on the system
    #   Increase physical memory or swap space
    #   Check if swap backing store is full
    #   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
    #   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
    #   Decrease number of Java threads
    #   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
    #   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
    # This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
    #
    #  Out of Memory Error (gcTaskThread.cpp:46), pid=2250, tid=140227064182528
    #
    # JRE version: 7.0_25-b15
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007f8920007800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2251, stack(0x00007f8928493000,0x00007f8928594000)]

    Stack: [0x00007f8928493000,0x00007f8928594000],  sp=0x00007f89285925d0,  free space=1021k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [libjvm.so+0x8a1d3a]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ea
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4071fb]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, char const*)+0x9b
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4b3e2a]  GCTaskThread::GCTaskThread(GCTaskManager*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0xfa
    V  [libjvm.so+0x4b2896]  GCTaskManager::initialize()+0x266
    V  [libjvm.so+0x75dc4f]  ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x6cf
    V  [libjvm.so+0x87a078]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0xb8
    V  [libjvm.so+0x87c7ed]  universe_init()+0x7d
    V  [libjvm.so+0x500315]  init_globals()+0x65
    V  [libjvm.so+0x863a62]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x1e2
    V  [libjvm.so+0x55ff34]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
    C  [libjli.so+0x2f8e]  JavaMain+0x9e


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )

    Other Threads:

    =>0x00007f8920007800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=2251, stack(0x00007f8928493000,0x00007f8928594000)]

    VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    GC Heap History (0 events):
    No events

    Deoptimization events (0 events):
    No events

    Internal exceptions (0 events):
    No events

    Events (0 events):
    No events


    Dynamic libraries:
    00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 9384                               /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
    00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 ca:01 9384                               /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
    01f54000-01f75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    86600000-87ac0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    87ac0000-8b800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    8b800000-905b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    905b0000-d92b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    d92b0000-db980000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    db980000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f891d000000-7f891d270000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f891d270000-7f8920022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8920022000-7f8924000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925555000-7f892574d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892574d000-7f892574e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892574e000-7f892584e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892584e000-7f892584f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892584f000-7f892595a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2252]
    7f892595a000-7f8925978000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925978000-7f892599f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892599f000-7f8925be6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925be6000-7f8925bf1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925bf1000-7f8925c0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925c0f000-7f8925c36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925c36000-7f8925e7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925e7c000-7f8925e90000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925e90000-7f8925fb3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925fb3000-7f8925fb4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8925fb4000-7f8925fcf000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17790                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
    7f8925fcf000-7f89261ce000 ---p 0001b000 ca:01 17790                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
    7f89261ce000-7f89261cf000 rw-p 0001a000 ca:01 17790                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
    7f89261cf000-7f89261db000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17544                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
    7f89261db000-7f89263da000 ---p 0000c000 ca:01 17544                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
    7f89263da000-7f89263db000 r--p 0000b000 ca:01 17544                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
    7f89263db000-7f89263dc000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 17544                      /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
    7f89263dc000-7f8926405000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17571                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
    7f8926405000-7f8926605000 ---p 00029000 ca:01 17571                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
    7f8926605000-7f8926607000 rw-p 00029000 ca:01 17571                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
    7f8926607000-7f8926614000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17789                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
    7f8926614000-7f8926813000 ---p 0000d000 ca:01 17789                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
    7f8926813000-7f8926815000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 17789                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
    7f8926815000-7f892681c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17559                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
    7f892681c000-7f8926a1b000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 17559                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
    7f8926a1b000-7f8926a1c000 r--p 00006000 ca:01 17559                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
    7f8926a1c000-7f8926a1d000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 17559                      /lib64/librt-2.12.so
    7f8926a1d000-7f8926a9f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17537                      /lib64/libm-2.12.so
    7f8926a9f000-7f8926c9e000 ---p 00082000 ca:01 17537                      /lib64/libm-2.12.so
    7f8926c9e000-7f8926c9f000 r--p 00081000 ca:01 17537                      /lib64/libm-2.12.so
    7f8926c9f000-7f8926ca0000 rw-p 00082000 ca:01 17537                      /lib64/libm-2.12.so
    7f8926ca0000-7f89276e1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17795                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
    7f89276e1000-7f89278e1000 ---p 00a41000 ca:01 17795                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
    7f89278e1000-7f8927984000 rw-p 00a41000 ca:01 17795                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
    7f8927984000-7f89279c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f89279c0000-7f8927b41000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7616                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    7f8927b41000-7f8927d41000 ---p 00181000 ca:01 7616                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    7f8927d41000-7f8927d45000 r--p 00181000 ca:01 7616                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    7f8927d45000-7f8927d46000 rw-p 00185000 ca:01 7616                       /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    7f8927d46000-7f8927d4c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8927d4c000-7f8927d4e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 17535                      /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    7f8927d4e000-7f8927f4e000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 17535                      /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    7f8927f4e000-7f8927f4f000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 17535                      /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    7f8927f4f000-7f8927f50000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 17535                      /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    7f8927f50000-7f8927f66000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 16704                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
    7f8927f66000-7f8928166000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 16704                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
    7f8928166000-7f8928167000 rw-p 00016000 ca:01 16704                      /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
    7f8928167000-7f892817e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7640                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    7f892817e000-7f892837d000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 7640                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    7f892837d000-7f892837e000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 7640                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    7f892837e000-7f892837f000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 7640                       /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    7f892837f000-7f8928383000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8928383000-7f89283a1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 9381                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    7f89283cb000-7f89283d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f89283d5000-7f892848b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892848b000-7f8928493000 rw-s 00000000 ca:01 8174                       /tmp/hsperfdata_gurustrade/2250
    7f8928493000-7f8928496000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f8928496000-7f8928598000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:2251]
    7f892859b000-7f892859e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892859e000-7f892859f000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f892859f000-7f89285a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7f89285a0000-7f89285a1000 r--p 0001d000 ca:01 9381                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    7f89285a1000-7f89285a2000 rw-p 0001e000 ca:01 9381                       /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    7f89285a2000-7f89285a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fff64527000-7fff64548000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
    7fff645ff000-7fff64600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
    ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

    VM Arguments:
    java_command: /home/gurustrade/proj/versions/trunk/gt_engine/gt_engine.jar
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
    SHELL=/bin/sh

    Signal Handlers:
    SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x8a26a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x8a26a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x73f3d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x73f3d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x73f3d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x73f3d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x73ed20], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
    SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
    SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS:Linux
    uname:Linux 3.4.48-45.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 12 02:04:44 UTC 2013 x86_64
    libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12 
    rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 1024, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
    load average:1.01 1.04 1.10

    /proc/meminfo:
    MemTotal:        7633612 kB
    MemFree:         5784036 kB
    Buffers:          186424 kB
    Cached:          1025752 kB
    SwapCached:            0 kB
    Active:           980284 kB
    Inactive:         706036 kB
    Active(anon):     474096 kB
    Inactive(anon):      100 kB
    Active(file):     506188 kB
    Inactive(file):   705936 kB
    Unevictable:           0 kB
    Mlocked:               0 kB
    SwapTotal:             0 kB
    SwapFree:              0 kB
    Dirty:                88 kB
    Writeback:             0 kB
    AnonPages:        474084 kB
    Mapped:            43752 kB
    Shmem:               156 kB
    Slab:             103892 kB
    SReclaimable:      84548 kB
    SUnreclaim:        19344 kB
    KernelStack:        9032 kB
    PageTables:        20180 kB
    NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    Bounce:                0 kB
    WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    CommitLimit:     3816804 kB
    Committed_AS:    2130476 kB
    VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
    VmallocUsed:       23908 kB
    VmallocChunk:   34359714455 kB
    AnonHugePages:         0 kB
    HugePages_Total:       0
    HugePages_Free:        0
    HugePages_Rsvd:        0
    HugePages_Surp:        0
    Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
    DirectMap4k:     7872512 kB
    DirectMap2M:           0 kB


    CPU:total 2 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

    /proc/cpuinfo:
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 23
    model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
    stepping    : 10
    microcode   : 0xa07
    cpu MHz     : 2660.000
    cache size  : 6144 KB
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
    bogomips    : 5320.00
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    processor   : 1
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 23
    model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
    stepping    : 10
    microcode   : 0xa07
    cpu MHz     : 2660.000
    cache size  : 6144 KB
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 13
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu tsc msr pae cx8 cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
    bogomips    : 5320.00
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:



    Memory: 4k page, physical 7633612k(5784036k free), swap 0k(0k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_25-b15),   built on Jun  5 2013 20:48:36 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

    time: Mon Aug  5 16:11:16 2013
    elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Also, I use threadpoolexecutor with 30 core threads and 100 max (never user more than 30 although at some times I use all 30)

Finally, I user bonecp connection pool with 50 connections

Any suggestions?
:)

After suggestion, I added a heap dump after running the application from my local pc.
How can I continue from here?
Are the critical orange jumps important?, or just the used important?
[image]

Comment: Suggestion: create a [heap dump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064427/recommendations-for-a-heap-analysis-tool-for-java) and figure out what is causing this. Not visible here.

Comment: It looks like the JVM crashed on startup, as witnessed by the fact that the crash comes from trying to create a thread for the GC, the lack of application threads, and `VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)`. Does the application start copies of itself in separates JVMs?

Comment: As you are running a virtual machine on a shared machine, is it possible the real machine is running out of memory?

Comment: joni - no, peter - no

Answer (score 13):

I was able to resolve an almost identical error by following the advice given by:

https://confluence.csiro.au/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=278167841

Essentially, they state:

> When the Java Virtual Machine starts, by default it spawns a number of Garbage Collection (GC) threads, which are used for parallel GC operations … the number of such threads is calculated by this formula: (ncpus <= 8) ? ncpus : 3 + ((ncpus * 5) / 8) … Because of the creation of these many threads … the program will automatically reach the system limit …

I limited the number of garbage collecting threads using the environment variable, like so:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2"
```

Not sure about the overall performance hit regarding GC, but at least today's work is done.

Please check the original post for more options.

Good Luck, 
- Stu

Comment: I had exact same issue and this fixed it. Guess my machine has too many cores!

Comment: I cannot able to access your link @Stu.

Answer (score 1):

Please try 64 bit version of Java if you are using 32 bit version,

Also add new JVM argument , "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \ "   which clear some unused class objects

Comment: i use 64, i'll add that

Answer (score 1):

If you have more physical ram available use that . It seems that the heap size allocated  is only 1656 mb which perhaps is not enough.
Try running java jar file with two switches -xmx4096mb and -xms 2048
Then monitor the usage , perhaps the memory requirement  is too large for your application , if you still run out of memory after sometime then it needs further investigation to check if your code is leaking memory.
Hope this helps , let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Heap is only part of the equation.  Have a look at total resident memory - it includes heap and off heap contributions.  Off heap includes mapped JARs, thread stacks (~1MB per thread), perm gen, etc.  SO has a number of questions on how to do it on Linux.

Comment: how can i monitor these "Off heap"s?

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to decode the dump data, I'll observe that there are basically three cases for running a JVM out of memory:

1. Having a structure (list of lists or whatnot) that is allowed to accumulate masses of unused (but still referenced) data.
2. Leaving various "handles" open -- file handles, threads, data base operations.  Especially if using an API with a native component you can potentially leave a lot of stuff outside of the reach of GC.
3. Making a single extremely large request (or a "burst" of such requests).

Kind of in-between here would be classes.  If you run a app that dynamically creates and loads classes, you must properly use individual class loaders to make the classes collectable.

Comment: If you're loading a class that you want to be able to unload later when it's no longer needed you need to create a "user class loader" specifically for it (or for a group of related classes that should be unloaded together).  This is because the class and class loader essentially reference each other, so using the regular class loader locks the class in place and makes it impossible to collect.  It's a bit involved, and I've never actually needed to do this (at least not for 10 years or so), so you'll have to look up the details.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the latest jdk.
Please try installing `java-11-openjdk`